# Linear transformations and their kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Am I correct to assume all of the following are linear transformations? I tested all 3 for the 2 conditions $T(A_1+A_2)$ and $T(kA)$ but I was unsure about if (a) was a linear transformation. The other thing I was unsure was what to use as the kernel for each linear transformation

a) $T(A) = A^2$

I was unsure if this was even a linear transformation as $A^2$ was non-linear
For the kernel, $ker(T)$ is it enough to use $ker(T) = (A$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2 \mid T(A) = 0v)$ or do I need to specify the vector A such that $T(A) = 0v$? In which case am I allowed to use $A = 0v$?

b) $T(A) = trace(A)$

For the kernel I know that the diagonal of A must sum to 0 for $T(A) = 0$ so could I use T(A) where $A = \pmatrix{0 & a \\ c & 0}$ where the diagonal of A is 0?

c) $T(A) = A + A^T$ (transpose)

Again the $ker(T)$ should be $T(A) = 0v$ but I'm not sure what vector to use for $A$, can I just the trivial $0v$ such that $A + A^T$ will result in $0v$?

Comment: $(a)$ is not a linear transformation.  $T(kA) = (kA)^2 = k^2A^2 \ne kA^2$.  Thus $T$ is not a homomorphism.  Kernels are only defined for homomorphisms.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $(b)$ is a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678437/consider-the-trace-map-m-n-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-what-is-its-kernel) and $(c)$ is close to a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317978/linear-transformations-kernel-range) (it's actually on $A-A^T$, but the same idea works for both.

Comment: My answer to (b) is similar but I know the dimension of A. for (c) I'm not quite sure I understand the answer and how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part a**

$T_a$ is not a linear transformation because $$T_a(kA)=(kA)^2=k^2A^2\ne kA^2$$ Thus T is not a homomorphism. Kernels are only defined for homomorphisms.

**Part b**

Because $T_b(A)=\operatorname{trace}(A)$, the kernel of this linear transformation (you can prove for yourself that this is in fact a linear transformation) is just the set of *tracefree* matrices.  I.e.  $$\operatorname{ker}(T_b) = \{A \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb K) \mid \operatorname{trace}(A) = 0\}$$

The space of $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n^2$.  The off-diagonal terms don't affect the trace of a matrices, so they can all be freely chosen.  For the diagonal, you really one have $1$ set value.  That is, if you arbitrarily chose $n-1$ of the diagonal elements, you could still make this matrix traceless by setting the last element equal to the sum of the negative of each of the $n-1$ elements you chose.  So every element of this matrix is free except $1$.  Thus the dimension of the kernel of $T_b$ is $n^2-1$.

Thus we can find a basis for this kernel by taking

1. the matrices with all $0$ elements except $1$ in $M_{ij}$ with $i\ne j$.  There are $n^2-n$ such matrices.
2. the matrices with $0$ elements everywhere except $1$ in $M_{ii}$ where $i \ne n$ and $-1$ in $M_{i+1,i+1}$.  There are $n-1$ such elements.

Thus we've found $n^2-1$ linearly independent matrices in $\operatorname{ker}(T_b)$ -- i.e. a basis for this kernel.

Example:  If $n=2$, then $$\operatorname{ker}(T_b) = \operatorname{span}\left[ \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}, \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}\right]$$

**Part c**

$$T_c(A) = A+A^T \implies \operatorname{ker}(T_c) = \{A \in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb K) \mid A+A^T = 0\}$$

But if $A+A^T=0$, then $A=-A^T$.  Thus $\operatorname{ker}(T_c)$ is just the space of skew-symmetric matrices.  The diagonal of a skew-symmetric matrix must be populated with $0$'s -- there are $n$ such elements.  And every element below the diagonal is determined  by (because it's the negative of) an element above the diagonal -- there are $(n^2-n)/2$ such elements.  The elements above the diagonal are all free, though.  Thus there are $n^2 - n - (n^2-n)/2 = (n^2-n)/2$ free elements.

So now that we know the dimension of the space, we just need a basis to characterize the space.  It should be clear from the above arguments that the set of matrices with a $1$ in one position above the diagonal and a $-1$ in the corresponding location below the diagonal will form such a basis.

For example, if $n=3$, then $$\operatorname{ker}(T_c) = \operatorname{span}\left[ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0}, \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0}\right]$$